# integration the very concept

Tags: calculus, integration

so i was just taught about integration and one thing i do not understand is that say we integrate x dx from 1 to 2 ... there are an infinite number of numbers between them ... so how does the sum turn out to be finite ?

Comment: @Darthjedi When you picture integration as a limit process involving the addition of areas of rectangles, you should keep in mind that as you increase the number of rectangles, you decrease their individual area... You are adding more and more terms but each term is smaller and smaller.

Answer (score 2):

Integration has got nothing to do with adding up numbers, let alone all numbers between two bounds which would be clearly impossible. It is rather about computing the area of the region bounded by the curve of the function, the $x$-axis, and the two vertical lines defined by $x=1$ and $x=2$.

[image]

This computation can be done by considering the limit of a sum of rectangle areas whose width gets smaller and smaller (and this point of view is called Riemann integration), but you should not fall in the trap of thinking like a physicist (with "infinitesimal rectangles of width $dx$") if your goal is to study maths.

Comment: I get the need for simplification but saying that integration has nothing to do with adding up numbers may be a little too strong... It also does not need to have anything to do with areas.

Comment: @PierreCarre Well, the only way to make a link between integration and adding up numbers is by talking about general measure theory, I'm not sure the OP wants to hear about that. The link with areas, however, is pretty neat and does not require much stretching.

Comment: I'm not going to downvote, but your first sentence is really just wrong. Integration *is* about adding up numbers, since any elementary text will define a definite integral as a limit of partial sums (i.e., adding up numbers). Also, nowhere does OP say you should add up "all numbers between two bounds" -- he only says you would be adding up infinitely many terms (he doesn't explicitly state that the terms *are* the numbers, and I suspect he knows the integrand is involved). Besides, you yourself proceed to describe the integral as a limit of partial sums!

Comment: @MPW I do agree that, in a way, we are adding up numbers, but when you say "number" students understand numbers just like the ones that are marked down on the $x$-axis (and you inevitably end up with questions like this OP). It is essential to understand that the "numbers" that we are adding up have very little to do with the first ones that come to mind. Although mathematics doesn't really have a distinction between a number that would represent an area and a number that represents a linear distance, I do believe that it would be helpful to have one at undergraduate level.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier : Understood

Answer (score 2):

The integral is a limit of finite sums. The sums do indeed consist of more and more terms, but the individual terms are also smaller and smaller, which makes it plausible that the limit should exist.

For your example, say $f(x)=x$. You approximate the integral by a finite sum of $n$ terms, then let $n\to\infty$ (i.e., consider the behavior as the number of terms increases without bound). Suppose you divide the interval $[1,2]$ into $n$ subintervals of equal length $\Delta x= \tfrac{2-1}{n}=\tfrac1n$. Choose a point $x_k$ in the $k^{\textrm{th}}$ subinterval--I'll pick the right endpoint $x_k = 1+\tfrac{k}{n}$, so $$x_1=1+\tfrac 1n\in[1,1+\tfrac 1n]$$
$$x_2=1+\tfrac 2n\in[1+\tfrac 1n,1+\tfrac 2n]$$
$$\cdots$$
$$x_n = 1+\tfrac nn =2 \in [1+\tfrac{n-1}n, 2]$$
Our approximation to the integral using $n$ terms is
$$S_n = \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} f(x_k)\Delta x = \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}(\underbrace{1+\tfrac kn}_{f(x_k)})(\underbrace{\tfrac 1n}_{\Delta x})$$
Let's fiddle with it to try to get a closed form:
$$S_n = \tfrac 1n\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}(1+\tfrac kn) =
\tfrac 1n\left(\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}1+\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\tfrac kn\right)$$
$$= \tfrac 1n\left(n+\tfrac 1n \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}k\right)$$
$$=\tfrac 1n\left(n+\tfrac 1n \tfrac{n(n+1)}{2}\right)$$
$$=\tfrac 1n\left(n+\tfrac{n+1}{2}\right)$$
$$=\tfrac 1n\left(\tfrac{3n+1}{2}\right)$$
$$= \tfrac 32 + \tfrac 1{2n}$$
So our $S_n=\tfrac 32 + \tfrac 1{2n}$. The value of the integral is
$$\int\limits_1^2x\;dx = \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}S_n = \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left(\tfrac 32 + \tfrac 1{2n}\right)= \tfrac 32$$

Comment: your profile picture is very on-topic for this post

Comment: Ha, I suppose so, @clathratus. +1 for that.